# Recursive process tree output is different when forwarded via pipe

Tags: c, macos, unix, recursion, fork

I've examined the same piece of code that should create process tree recursively:

```
void proc_recurse(int layer)
{
    if(layer<=0) return;
    switch(fork()){
    case 0:
        proc_recurse(layer-1);
        printf("%d: child layer = %d\n", getpid(), layer);
        break;
    case -1:
        printf(stderr,"%d: fork failed\n", getpid());
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d: parent \n", getpid());
        break;
    }
}

int  main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm grandParent %d n = %d \n", getpid(), n);

    proc_recurse(n);
}
```

[image]

Obviously, the results are completely different when using pipe. I could observe that the `fork` returns to where the code starts (notice the 'grandParent' message that repeats itself in the output). Can anyone explain to me the nature of this difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is buffering. If you add a call to `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf`s the problem disappears:

```
void proc_recurse(int layer)
{
    if(layer<=0) return;
    switch(fork()){
    case 0:
        proc_recurse(layer-1);
        printf("%d: child layer = %d\n", getpid(), layer);
        break;
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr,"%d: fork failed\n", getpid());
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d: parent \n", getpid());
        break;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

int  main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm grandParent %d n = %d \n", getpid(), n);
    fflush(stdout);
    proc_recurse(n);
}
```

Try run:

```
$ ./a.out 5 | less
I'm grandParent 7124 n = 5 
7124: parent 
7126: parent 
7126: child layer = 5
7127: parent 
7127: child layer = 4
7127: child layer = 5
7128: parent 
7128: child layer = 3
7128: child layer = 4
7128: child layer = 5
7129: parent 
7130: child layer = 1
7130: child layer = 2
7130: child layer = 3
7130: child layer = 4
7130: child layer = 5
7129: child layer = 2
7129: child layer = 3
7129: child layer = 4
7129: child layer = 5
```

---

The issue is that `stdout` is generally unbuffered or line buffered *when performing output to the terminal*. However once you pipe the output then a buffer is used (something like a 4K buffer, but it depends). This means that the "grandParent" line is *not* given in output from the main process immediately, the fork then makes it so that the child processes now have a copy of this buffer containing this line and when they write and finally perform the output you end up with repeated contents.

This is a common mistake when writing programs using `fork` etc. Before performing a `fork` you should `fflush` the output to avoid this can of issue.